Getting Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" error with node 18 when run against mobile Apps
I have webdriverio + cucumberjs based tests and When using node 18, I,m getting error - http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
Setup:
node v18.20.3 (npm v10.7.0)
appium@2.8.0
xcuitest@5.8.1

I am able to run against iOS safari browser but fails to runs against any mobile App. But my same tests works when I use node 16.
node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
appium@2.8.0
xcuitest@5.8.1

Error log:
Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
    at Runtime.runTestRunHooks (/private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/run_test_run_hooks.js:23:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Runtime.start (/private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/index.js:53:9)
    at async runCucumber (/private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/api/run_cucumber.js:106:21) {
  jse_shortmsg: 'a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: node_modules/<my-package>/dist/myfile.js:72',
  jse_cause: Error: Failed to create session.
  Unable to connect to "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
  If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
      at startWebDriverSession (file:///private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async WebDriver.newSession (file:///private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:26:45)
      at async remote (file:///private/tmp/scratchEmNi2G.scratch/test-packagesbz9OA/node_modules/<my-package>/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:48:22),
  jse_info: {},
  cause: [Function: ve_cause]


I had to change hostname from localhost to 127.0.0.1. (More info: webdriverio/webdriverio#8763)

Appium doesn't use "/wd/hub" anymore, or at least it doesn't require it externally.
This is the output from Appium 2.11 server command when Appium is started:
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
    http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)

When I was running the Appium server pre-2.0, it used to show the "/wd/hub" included on the output (at least this is what I remember).
For reference, I tried running my tests without an Appium server and here is my error:
Unable to connect to "http://0.0.0.0:4723/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.

As you can see, it is trying to access a URL that doesn't have a "wd/hub".
I'm not sure if it helps but I explicitly remember omiting "wd/hub".
A copy of my wdio.conf.js:
capabilities: [{
        port: 4723,
        platformName: "Android",
        "appium:noReset": true,
        "appium:fullReset": false,
        "appium:appPackage": "your.app.here",
        "appium:appActivity": "your.app.here.MainActivity",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "appium:autoGrantPermissions": true
    }],
baseUrl: 'http://localhost',

